# Problem with getting div to transform within another div

Tags: html, css, transform

My goal is to basically create a button where the button rotates/tilts slightly on hover but the text does not. https://codepen.io/kyannashanice/pen/QWveOMg

I stacked the text and button in seperate div and had the effect trigger on hover but for some reason it wouldn't center the button and text inside the container. I found a solution to that issue and now instead of a slight tilt the button is moving outside of the container.

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 70%;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.text-overlay {
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: cream;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -10;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.spin>button {
  display: block;
  /* removes bottom margin/whitespace */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}

.container:hover .spin>button {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="spin">
    <button class="button">  </button>
  </div>

  <div class="text-overlay"> READ <br> MORE </div>

</div>
```

I would appreciate some help to fix this! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the code you have provided, you just need to *remove* the  ***transform: translate*** on the elements and then tweak the  ***top and left positions*** to properly place the text on top of the center of your button.

If the snippit is not what you're looking for, let me know and I can edit it or delete the answer.

```css
.container {
 height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 70%;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.text-overlay {
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%; 
  left: 45%;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: cream;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -10;
}

/* Spin Effect */
.spin > button {
  display: block;
  /* removes bottom margin/whitespace */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}

.container:hover .spin > button {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="spin">
    <button class="button">  </button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="text-overlay"> READ <br> MORE </div>
  
</div>
```